# Creating Patterns in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop

There is probably a really simple solution to this, but I just can't figure it out. I have created a patter of asterisks that is generated by this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{

    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i<=10; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j<i; j++)
            cout << "*";
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n\n";
    for (j = 10; j>0; j--)
    {
        for (i = 0; i<j; i++)
            cout << "*";
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    for (j = 10; j>0; j--)
    {
        for (i = 0; i<j; i++)
            cout << "*";
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    for (i = 0; i<=10; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j<i; j++)
            cout << "*";
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;

}
```

As you can see the code generates four blocks of asterisk patterns. My issue is that I need the last two blocks to look like this:

```
**********
 *********
  ********
   *******
    ******
     *****
      ****
       ***
        **
         *

         *
        **
       ***
      ****
     *****
    ******
   *******
  ********
 *********
**********
```

I am thinking I need another for-loop inside these two that will make each line begin with an appropriate number of blank spaces, but I am stuck trying to formulate this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The "design-pattern" tag is not appropriate here (please approve the edit that removes it). Here it's about a visual pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest (without wierd syntax & tricks) would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>


int main(){


    const int SIZE = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i){ //increment index

        std::cout << std::setw(i + 1); //print whitespace

        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE - i; j++){
            std::cout << '*'; //print asterisks
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }



    for (int i = SIZE; i >= 0; --i){ //decrement index

        std::cout << std::setw(i + 1); //print whitespace

        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE - i; j++){
            std::cout << '*'; //print asterisks
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
**********
 *********
  ********
   *******
    ******
     *****
      ****
       ***
        **
         *

         *
        **
       ***
      ****
     *****
    ******
   *******
  ********
 *********
**********
```

you could also change `SIZE` because fun:

```
******************************
 *****************************
  ****************************
   ***************************
    **************************
     *************************
      ************************
       ***********************
        **********************
         *********************
          ********************
           *******************
            ******************
             *****************
              ****************
               ***************
                **************
                 *************
                  ************
                   ***********
                    **********
                     *********
                      ********
                       *******
                        ******
                         *****
                          ****
                           ***
                            **
                             *

                             *
                            **
                           ***
                          ****
                         *****
                        ******
                       *******
                      ********
                     *********
                    **********
                   ***********
                  ************
                 *************
                **************
               ***************
              ****************
             *****************
            ******************
           *******************
          ********************
         *********************
        **********************
       ***********************
      ************************
     *************************
    **************************
   ***************************
  ****************************
 *****************************
******************************
```

Answer (score 0):

#include 
using namespace std;

int main()
{

```
int i, j;

for (j = 10; j>0; j--)
{
     for(i=j;i<10;i++)
        cout<<  " ";
     for (i = 0; i<j; i++)
        cout << "*";

    cout << "\n";
}
cout << "\n";
for (i = 0; i<=10; i++)
{
    for(j=i;j<10;j++)
        cout<<  " ";

    for (j = 0; j<i; j++)
        cout << "*";
    cout << "\n";
}
return 0;
```

}

I think you can use the above code,you should calculate how many spaces before you loop print "*"

Answer (score 0):

What with an alternative that uses iomanip to define a width for the output, and print a string made of asterixes ?  This would make the code much simpler !

And in order to avoid repeating yourself, you could then embed this in a loop (one iteration would be equilvalent to 1 of your former blocks) and toggle increasing and decreasing depending if the counter z is odd (`z & 1` false) or even.

So your whole program would look like:

```
for (int z=0; z<4; z++) {
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        cout << setw(10) << string( (z&1 ? i:10-i), '*')<<endl; 
}
```

**[Online demo](https://ideone.com/Hp7zwh)**